# How to stop caching in liferay?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, liferay, portlet

The site I am working on requires very rapid changes in content some times, but the portlets are keeping cache and not reflecting changes for certain time. I need immediate change. Some sources suggests using portal-developer.properties. But using portal-developer.properties in production is not proper I guess. Please suggest.

Comment: Can you specify what areas you need immediate change? Themes (CSS, JS, images), portlet HTML, data persistence, RSS, webcontent or others? Because there are some different caches in Liferay, some make sense to change, some don't (like you say with portal-developer.properties). Are you clustering?

Comment: @Olaf Kock: I need to see the changes of webcontent in my portlets.

Comment: Do you have more than one Liferay server? I.e. did you setup a cluster? IMHO portal-developer.properties would not help you with WebContent, but I see this behaviour when clustering is not set up correctly (or when you modify the database content directly, bypassing the API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to do with `<expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>` in portlet.xml. Please suggest